# Indoor Growing - Light Selection

Tags: indoors, light, led

I have undercabinet lighting using f8t5/cw fluorescent bulbs.  I want to replace these with lights that will allow small plants (ex. basil, oregano, mint, and other low maintenance herbs) to grow leaves quickly and with flavor.

This is not a product recommendation request.  I just don't know where to start in my search.
What are the "terms of art" or other industry-specific search terms I can use to find what I'm looking for?

Example: I tried "grow lights f8t5/cw" but am pretty sure there is a better way to locate what I need.

Comment: Aquarium lighting" will bring up good and not good information on lights for plants.

Answer (score 1):

It seems these are small, 12 inch fluorescent bulb fixtures? I don't think you can significantly increase light output with those, just by putting in different bulbs.
Even LED replacement bulbs in that size have a max output of about 500 lumens. The minimum light intensity for growing plants would be about 3000 lumens per square foot. 7000 lumens/sq.ft. would be better.
I would suggest new fixtures that take high output T5 fluorescent bulbs, or LED bulbs of equivalent light output.

Comment: Thank you.  That is possible given our setup.